# onmouseenter behaves like onmousemove when changing content

Tags: javascript

blueFairyAnimation.animate essentialy removes and appends a new image in animationContainer every 150ms to create an animation. The problem is that when this happens onmouseenter starts behaving like onmousemove.

```
animationContainerBlue.onmouseenter = function () {
    console.log('onmouseenter');
    blueFairyAnimation.animate(150, true);
};
```

This is how i change animationContainerBlues content (targetElement is animationContainerBlues):

```
    targetElement.innerHTML = '';
    targetElement.appendChild(element);
```

There is a live [example](http://gasterm.wienerwurstel.com/Kindergarden/)

EDIT: I squashed the image in the left part of the div. When entering from the no-image side there is no problem, but when i overlap the changing content along with the div then the onmouseenter goes berserk..